# automated way to start debuging Android program in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, ui-automation

Is there way to automate debug start sequence in eclipse?

Right now, after every deployment I have to
 - go to DDMS perspective, devices tab
 - find my process in process list and select it. Sometimes my process is last, but more often that not process list is in random order.
 - select my process
 - click `Debug` button

I deploy my app only from Maven build (not directly from IDE). My app is mutli-module project, and I want to debug library. The library is not started directly - it is used by another application.

Comment: Click the debug button, to the left of the green run button in the tool bar to launch the app in debug mode

Comment: @reactivemobile- that would do the trick indeed- in case of standard application. But my app is library, build from maven. I added more details to orginal questions.

Comment: You can click the DDMS devices tab and start typing your package name to jump to yours but this only helps a little

Comment: @reactivemobile - a little step in right direction, indeed. I mave name `com.<companyName>.<departamentName>.<projectName>` package. There are two dozen `com.` packages, and a few `com.<companyName>` already. Too bad that the search starts from first letter, not from any letter.